# force ssh to use agent, without fallback to directly accessing the IdentityFile

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, gpg, ssh-agent

Company policy requires some ssh keys to be stored securely, e.g. on dedicated USB device. Using keys not stored on the host machine works flawlessly using gnupg with `enable-ssh-support`, even when multiple keys are used:

```
Host example.com
    HostName ssh.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/smartcard.pub
Host example.net
    HostName git.example.net
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/another-smartcard.pub
Host example.org
    HostName sftp.example.org
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

IdentitiesOnly yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

However, when the hardware is unplugged, gpg removes the key from the agent and subsequent ssh calls result in:

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/smartcard.pub':
```

This seems odd, as both ssh and ssh-agent should be well aware that that file contains a public key only. **Is there a good way of making ssh fail verbosely if it has no way of accessing the specified key, instead of asking for a (pointless) passphrase?**

Incomplete solutions:

1. remove `IdentitiesOnly` - ssh will then try *all usable keys* as expected - but leads to trouble with servers limiting authentication attempts per session
2. wrap ssh in some way `alias ssh='grep ^4096 <(ssh-add -l)' && ssh'` - works, but will cause headache in case someone ever wants to find out why his ssh setup is broken

Comment: Closely related: [Force the use of a gpg-key as an ssh-key for a given server](https://serverfault.com/q/906871/250204)

Answer (score 1):

Use OpenSSH 7.9 or later, it will at least print *some* error:

```
$ ssh example.com
Load key "/home/user/.ssh/smartcard.pub": invalid format
user@example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```